# How can i await the result from setInterval so i can return it from the custom pipe in angular?

Tags: angular

I have custom pipe where i need to recacalculate the remaining time of the appointment date every one second and return it to the HTML.

But i can't await it the result.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'appointmentTest'
})
export class AppointmentPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, date: any): unknown {
  var difference;
      setInterval(() => {
        difference = moment.duration(
          moment(date, "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm").diff(moment()))['_data'];
          //here i get the result properly
          console.log(difference);
      },1000)
    
   //here is undefined
   console.log(difference);
   return `Hours: ${difference.hours} Days: ${difference.days} Minutes: 
  ${difference.minutes} Seconds: ${difference.seconds}`;
  }

}
```

in the setInterval the difference is initialised like it should,but when i try to return it after the setInterval ending the difference is undefined.

HTML

```
  <ul *ngFor="let appointment of user_maked_appointments">
          <li class="list-group-item">{{ name | appointmentTest:appointment.time_remaining }}</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe a better solution to your problem is to use RXJS interval: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval

Comment: i have a lot of objects in array where i have time_remaining property.I am sending that value in the custom pipe i am recaculating the remaining time until that date, and i am returning that value back. Can you please write an example how that should look with the RXJS? I need set Interval to calculate the remaining time for each object in the user_maked_appointments

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm already did made an example with `interval`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an observable with your pipe and chain the async pipe

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { interval, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'appointmentTest'
})
export class AppointmentPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, date: any): Observable<string> {
    return interval(1000).pipe(
      map(() => moment.duration(moment(date, "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm").diff(moment()))['_data']),
      map(difference => `Hours: ${difference.hours} Days: ${difference.days} Minutes:${difference.minutes} Seconds: ${difference.seconds}`),
    );
  }

}
```

```
<ul *ngFor="let appointment of user_maked_appointments">
  <li class="list-group-item">{{ name | appointmentTest:appointment.time_remaining | async }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello Moxxi. I get red underlines on the whole code in the transform method with your example.Can you please correct it ?

Comment: I get the error after the second map, so after ,map()

Comment: @andrej.boshkoski1 edited, I copied a `)` too much.

Answer (score 0):

first: your pipe should be **impure** `pure: fase`. second: you should refactor pipe to "save" its current value and return it on call. as transform method gets called multiple times recreation of setInterval is not required

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'appointmentTest',
  pure: false
})
export class AppointmentPipe implements PipeTransform {
  difference;
  intervalId;
  transform(value: any, date: any): string {
      
     this.updateDiff(date);
     if(!this.intervalId) {
        this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
           this.updateDiff(date);
        },1000)
    }
   return `Hours: ${difference.hours} Days: ${difference.days} Minutes: 
  ${difference.minutes} Seconds: ${difference.seconds}`;
  }
  
  updateDiff(date) {
    this.difference = moment.duration(
          moment(date, "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm").diff(moment()))['_data'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. But with this example i get ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Comment: I am not sure that pipe is the reason of this error. could there be anything else in your component?

Comment: No, the anoter solution from Moxxi i guess worked because there is async solution there